# How to add email verification to my PHP register script

Tags: php, email, salt, verification

I have recently made a login and register script which works fine but I want it to more secure from spammers and I was wondering if anyone know how to make an email verification system.

How could I make this script add email verification to it. I hope this made sense

```
    <?php 
    require("php/bp-connection.php"); 

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter a username."); 
        } 

        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter a password."); 
        } 

        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
        } 

        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This username is already in use"); 
        } 

        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This email address is already registered"); 
        } 

        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 

        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 

            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        header("Location: login.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

?> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Register | BinaryPaw</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bp-grid.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bp-styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include 'php/bp-siteBar.php';
?>

<div class="container">
    <?php
        include 'php/bp-sideBar.php';
    ?>

    <div class="span4">
        <h1>User Registration</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post"> 
        <div class="space1">
            <label>Username</label> 
        </div>

        <div class="space2">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="username" value="" /> 
        </div>

        <div class="space1">
            <label>Email</label> 
        </div>

        <div class="space2">
            <input type="text" name="email" class="email" value="" /> 
        </div>

        <div class="space1">
            <label>Password</label> 
        </div>

        <div class="space2">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="password" value="" /> 
        </div>

        <div class="space3">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="space3"></div>

    <div class="span10" id="footer">
        <h6>Created by Mathew Berry &copy2013 </h6>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Generate a hash, save it in your database and add a timestamp. Send a link to the mailaddress and let the user click the link. After that enable the user in the database and remove the hash.

Comment: add another column to the table such as "status" with enum values `verified,notverified` then once you inserted the record send an email to the use, send a link with a parameter like ?check=randomstring and save this random string also with user detail, then, the rest is just usual things

Comment: Using the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is much more convenient, and generates a better suited BCrypt hash with a cryptographically safe salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple send a code to user email address and create a page to verify the code and if code verify then register the user

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
$email_id=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$code=substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample');

$insert=mysql_query("insert into verify values('','$email','$pass','$code')");
$db_id=mysql_insert_id();

$message = "Your Activation Code is ".$code."";
$to=$email;
$subject="Activation Code For Talkerscode.com";
$from = 'your email';
$body='Your Activation Code is '.$code.' Please Click On This link <a href="verification.php">Verify.php?id='.$db_id.'&code='.$code.'</a>to activate your account.';
$headers = "From:".$from;
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

echo "An Activation Code Is Sent To You Check You Emails";
}
```

to verify the code

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$code=$_GET['id'];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample');
$select=mysql_query("select email,password from verify where id='$id' and code='$code'");
if(mysql_num_rows($select)==1)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $email=$row['email'];
        $password=$row['password'];
    }
    $insert_user=mysql_query("insert into verified_user values('','$email','$password')");
    $delete=mysql_query("delete from verify where id='$id' and code='$code'");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple send a code to user email address and create a page to verify the code and if code verify then register the user

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
$email_id=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$code=substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample');

$insert=mysql_query("insert into verify values('','$email','$pass','$code')");
$db_id=mysql_insert_id();

$message = "Your Activation Code is ".$code."";
$to=$email;
$subject="Activation Code For Talkerscode.com";
$from = 'your email';
$body='Your Activation Code is '.$code.' Please Click On This link <a href="verification.php">Verify.php?id='.$db_id.'&code='.$code.'</a>to activate your account.';
$headers = "From:".$from;
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

echo "An Activation Code Is Sent To You Check You Emails";
}
```

to verify the code

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$code=$_GET['id'];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample');
$select=mysql_query("select email,password from verify where id='$id' and code='$code'");
if(mysql_num_rows($select)==1)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $email=$row['email'];
        $password=$row['password'];
    }
    $insert_user=mysql_query("insert into verified_user values('','$email','$password')");
    $delete=mysql_query("delete from verify where id='$id' and code='$code'");
}
}
```

complete tutorial here http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/account-verification-system-through-email-using-php.php

Answer (score -1):

You can add captcha to prevent from spammer on your form. It is more secure than anything else.

Comment: I disagree. It is not able to prevent spam. But can reduce spambots. But, a human going in can defeat it and does. There are ways to make life miserable for a spammer. Amongst other things, my script searches for words and phrases. Prevent pasting works, email verification, minimum word count, etc all cut things down to a minimum without the negative effects of reCAPTCHA which reduces submissions. Especially if you are on a VPN like we all should be. These techniques we use throughout many websites over the years, and while again, it can be defeated, it is rare, and does not reduce submissions